# Flex box not aligned with others

Tags: html, css, squarespace

```css
:root {
  --clr-primary: #f9baaa;
    --clr-graylight: #c13828;
  --clr-graymed: #c13828;
  --border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "Playfair Display", "Montserrat";
  background:square(#f9baaa);
}

main {
  margin: 0rem;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.testimonial-container {
  border-radius: square(--border-radius);
  padding: 2rem;
  width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0.75rem;
  background: #f9baaa;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&family=Playfair+Display:wght@400;500;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  
</head>

<body>
  <main>
       <h3>Here's a summary of what we'll cover together:</h3> 
    <div class="wrapper">    
<div class="testimonial-container">
 <h3 class="testimonial">Step 1: Language</h3>
        <div class="name">
          <p class="name">The language and questions we use internally play a big part in our life and affect our mindset. During our first session we will uncover the language you use and questions you ask yourself.</p>
        </div>
      </div> 
    
 <div class="testimonial-container">
        <h3 class="testimonial">Step 2: Values</h3>
        <div class="name">
          <p class="name">We will dedicate two sessions to getting you clarity on your values; what is important to you in life. We will also assess how these play a role in your life and how to get you more of them.</p>
        </div>
      </div>    
      
 <div class="testimonial-container">
        <h3 class="testimonial">Step 3: Beliefs</h3>
        <div class="name">
          <p class="name">Our fourth and fifth sessions will be focused on understanding your beliefs. This is the time where we tackle those little voices inside your head that may be holding you back.</p>
        </div>
      </div>   
      
<div class="testimonial-container">
        <h3 class="testimonial">Step 4: Identity</h3>
        <div class="name">
          <p class="name">During the identity session we will create your identity blueprint: Who are you? What do you do? How do you choose to live?</p>
        </div>
      </div> 
      
<div class="testimonial-container">
        <h3 class="testimonial">Step 5: Purpose</h3>
        <div class="name">
          <p class="name">We will then move on to identify your purpose. What makes you get up in the morning? Having a clear purpose can help you create goals, guide your life decisions and offer you a sense of direction.</p>
        </div>
      </div> 
      
<div class="testimonial-container">
        <h3 class="testimonial">Wrap-Up Session</h3>
        <div class="name">
          <p class="name">Lastly, we will end by looking at how you can move forward with this new understanding and clarity. How can you utilise what you’ve discovered to help you lead your best life?</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

[flex boxes I'm trying to align - first 1 is not aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOgNR.png)

Hello,

I'm trying to align my flex boxes (I have 6) - they are all aligned except for the first 1.

I have tried a few different things but quite new to this so not sure what will work. The last box was not aligning but I fixed that by inputting height: 350px.

I'm creating this on Squarespace - Paloma template.

Is someone able to offer any advice?

Thank you!

```css
:root {
  --clr-primary: #f9baaa;
    --clr-graylight: #c13828;
  --clr-graymed: #c13828;
  --border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "Playfair Display", "Montserrat";
  background:square(#f9baaa);
}

main {
  margin: 0rem;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.testimonial-container {
  border-radius: square(--border-radius);
  padding: 2rem;
  width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0.75rem;
  background: #f9baaa;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&family=Playfair+Display:wght@400;500;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  
</head>

<body>
  <main>
       <h3>Here's a summary of what we'll cover together:</h3> 
    <div class="wrapper">    
<div class="testimonial-container">
 <h3 class="testimonial">Step 1: Language</h3>
        <div class="name">
          <p class="name">The language and questions we use internally play a big part in our life and affect our mindset. During our first session we will uncover the language you use and questions you ask yourself.</p>
        </div>
      </div> 
    
 <div class="testimonial-container">
        <h3 class="testimonial">Step 2: Values</h3>
        <div class="name">
          <p class="name">We will dedicate two sessions to getting you clarity on your values; what is important to you in life. We will also assess how these play a role in your life and how to get you more of them.</p>
        </div>
      </div>    
      
 <div class="testimonial-container">
        <h3 class="testimonial">Step 3: Beliefs</h3>
        <div class="name">
          <p class="name">Our fourth and fifth sessions will be focused on understanding your beliefs. This is the time where we tackle those little voices inside your head that may be holding you back.</p>
        </div>
      </div>   
      
<div class="testimonial-container">
        <h3 class="testimonial">Step 4: Identity</h3>
        <div class="name">
          <p class="name">During the identity session we will create your identity blueprint: Who are you? What do you do? How do you choose to live?</p>
        </div>
      </div> 
      
<div class="testimonial-container">
        <h3 class="testimonial">Step 5: Purpose</h3>
        <div class="name">
          <p class="name">We will then move on to identify your purpose. What makes you get up in the morning? Having a clear purpose can help you create goals, guide your life decisions and offer you a sense of direction.</p>
        </div>
      </div> 
      
<div class="testimonial-container">
        <h3 class="testimonial">Wrap-Up Session</h3>
        <div class="name">
          <p class="name">Lastly, we will end by looking at how you can move forward with this new understanding and clarity. How can you utilise what you’ve discovered to help you lead your best life?</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: In the snippets they seem to align though? Did you confirm in different browsers?

Comment: Is there a particular browser that is causing you problems, or does this happen with all browsers?

Comment: Thank you @LilaQ - I have tried in Safari and Google Chrome on a Mac and for both the first box is not aligned. This is when I am viewing it in desktop mode (so 3 in a row) rather than mobile (when there is only 1 per row). I have attached a photo so you can see what I am seeing.

Comment: Thank you @RobJarvis - please see above comment re browsers.I have attached a photo so you can see what I am seeing. Do you think it is something to do with the Squarespace site?

Comment: Hm, I can't you your issue in the code snippets here, everything seems to align just fine (nothing like you have in your image). Try to inspect on the page itself, maybe there is some `:nth-child()` or `:first` from other styles that is messing with your CSS.

Comment: Thanks @LilaQ I'll have look :)

Comment: I think it must be an issue in the Squarespace editor as when I look at just the webpage normally it works. Thanks